# Why I can not create a thread with class object as parameter

Tags: c++, multithreading, caching

I tried to implement a multithreading cache in C++ 11. I tried to create threads in the main function and passed the putcache function and getcache function as parameter. And I passed class object c1 to the two functions as parameters. However, I found that the complier gave me a error like this: `In template: no matching constructor for initialization of '_Gp' (aka 'tuple<unique_ptr<std::__thread_struct>, void (*)(LRUCache), LRUCache>')`
Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>
#include <mutex>
using namespace std;
class LRUCache {
public:
    class Node {
    public:
        int key,val;
        Node* left,*right;
        Node(int _key,int _val):key(_key),val(_val),left(NULL),right(NULL) {}
    }*L,*R;
    unordered_map<int,Node*> m;
    int n;
    mutex mtx;
    condition_variable cv;
    void insert(Node* node)
    {
        Node* next=L->right;
        L->right=node;
        node->right=next;
        node->left=L;
        next->left=node;
    }
    void erase(Node* node) {
        node->left->right=node->right;
        node->right->left=node->left;
    }
    LRUCache(int capacity) {
        n=capacity;
        L=new Node(-1,-1),R=new Node(-1,-1);
        L->right=R;
        R->left=L;
    }

    int get(int key) {
        if(m.count(key)==0) return -1;
        mtx.lock();
        Node* node=m[key];
        erase(node);
        insert(node);
        return node->val;
        mtx.unlock();
    }

    void put(int key, int value) {
        mtx.lock();
        if(m.count(key)) {
            m[key]->val=value;
            erase(m[key]);
            insert(m[key]);
        } else {
            Node* node=new Node(key,value);
            if(m.size()==n) {
                Node* tmp=R->left;
                erase(tmp);
                m.erase(tmp->key);
            }
            insert(node);
            m[key]=node;
        }
        mtx.unlock();
    }
};
void putcache(LRUCache c) {
    for(int i=1;i<=10;i++) {
        c.put(i,i+10);
        this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
    }
}
void getcache(LRUCache c) {
    for(int i=1;i<=10;i++) {
        c.get(i);
        this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
    }
}

int main() {
    LRUCache c1(100);
    std::thread t1(putcache,c1);
    std::thread t2(getcache,c1);
}
```

Comment: `LRUCache` contains two non-copyable members (mutex and condition variable) so its copy constructor is deleted. You can't even do `putcache(c1)`.

Answer (score 1):

As @Nelfeal said:

> `LRUCache` contains two non-copyable members (mutex and condition variable) so its copy constructor is deleted.

You could not copy `LRUCache`, by passing the `c1` to the thread, you're copying it. Take a reference instead:

```cpp
void putcache(LRUCache& c);
void getcache(LRUCache& c);


LRUCache c1(100);
std::thread t1(putcache, std::ref(c1));
std::thread t2(getcache, std::ref(c1));
```

And I think making the thread a class member would better fit your needs:

```cpp
class LRUCache 
{
    void getcache();
    void putcache();
}

LRUCache c1(100);
std::thread t1(&LRUCache::putcache, &c1);
std::thread t2(&LRUCache::getcache, &c1);
```

Comment: I tried to modify my code in the second way you propose, however, it got such an error: Call to non-static member function without an object argument @thedemons

Comment: @Jacob sorry i missed a `&`, updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

`std::thread` makes a copy of its parameters to ensure they live long enough for the new thread to start up.  Also your `putcache` and `getcache` functions accept their parameters by value.  Your `LRUCache` class doesn't have a valid copy constructor though, so neither of those things can work.

If you want to pass a *reference* to `c1` to both threads, then you'll need to wrap the parameters in a `std::reference_wrapper` and make your `putcache` and `getcache` functions accept their parameters by value:

```
void putcache(LRUCache& c) { // <-------- NOTE: added &
    for(int i=1;i<=10;i++) {
        c.put(i,i+10);
        this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
    }
}
void getcache(LRUCache& c) { // <-------- NOTE: added &
    for(int i=1;i<=10;i++) {
        c.get(i);
        this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
    }
}

int main() {
    LRUCache c1(100);
    std::thread t1(putcache, std::ref(c1)); // <-------- NOTE: added std::ref
    std::thread t2(getcache, std::ref(c1)); // <-------- NOTE: added std::ref
    t1.join();
    t2.join();
}
```

Keep in mind that it's up to you to ensure that `c1` stays alive for the entire duration of your two threads.  In this case, I've `join`ed the two threads in `main` to ensure it doesn't end before they're finished.